# Python - move element (row and index) to the end based on index

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a Python series that looks like:

```
Good             4
Satisfactory     9
Strong          57
Total           72
Weak             2
```

How can I move the "Total 72" to the end?

It might have been different i.e. it might have been

```
Good             4
Total           72
Satisfactory     9
Strong          57
Weak             2
```

so I want to be able to move the rows with index "Total" to the end. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) by sorted index by keys for test if equal `Total`, it also working if no value `Total`, but not working if duplicated values in index:

```
s1 = s.reindex(sorted(s.index, key='Total'.__eq__))
print (s1)

Good           4
Satisfactory   9
Strong        57
Weak           2
Total         72
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

EDIT: If possible some duplicated values is possible compare values of index, get positions of mask by [`Index.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.argsort.html) and last change order by positions by [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
print (s)
Good             4
Satisfactory     9
Strong          57
Total           72
Satisfactory     2
Name: a, dtype: int64

s1 = s.iloc[(s.index =='Total').argsort()]
print (s1)
Good             4
Satisfactory     9
Strong          57
Satisfactory     2
Total           72
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I get an error `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` how do I fix that?

Comment: The second code gives me an error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Index'`